# How to include multiple search string in single code line

Tags: unix

I have a code which searches IN string in a file then puts those records in a different file for which I am using below:

```
cat ${ALL_CARDS} | grep -v ' IN ' | awk '{print $1}' > ${NO_EXEC_CARDS}
```

But now I have to include multiple search string along with IN like NE & ON so how to include those also in this code line

Comment: Your question is not fully clear to me. `grep -v ' IN '` prints the lines that don't match the pattern `' IN '`. Do you want to get all the lines that don't match any of the three patterns? In this case William Pursell's answer will fit. I suggest to [edit] your question and add more details to make it clear. Some sample input and expected output might also help.

Answer (score 1):

`cat | grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  Also, just using `awk` makes your question trivial:

```
awk '! /IN/ && ! /ON/ && ! /NE/ {print $1}' "$ALL_CARDS" > "$NO_EXEC_CARDS"
```

You have some additional whitespace in your `grep`, so perhaps you want:

```
awk '! / IN / && ! / ON / && ! / NE / {print $1}'
```

`awk` is well designed for this.  It simply reads each line, and if the expression does not match " IN " or " ON " or " NE ", then the action is executed.  You could also write this as:

```
awk '! (/ IN / || / ON / || / NE /) {print $1}'
```